# How to restore dump file in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, datapump

I want to restore a database in oracle 12c. I have done something for it but while importing data I got some errors about non-existing users in db.Because the database needs some users which must defined in oracle 12c. I created users for db which db needs but in oracle 12 creating user system was changed about session issues. I had to put c## expression in front username and problem still persists. I tried different methods to restore but it wasn't imported all tables and data. I think it's about the user problem.My question how can i create a user same as with the backup db user and restore database.

Comment: It would be good if you post the error details in the log.

Comment: I corrected the errors.

Comment: You mean you solved your issue? Could you please edit your question and add the resolution details alongwith the errors you encountered.

Comment: I meaned i edited my question.I still have trouble with my issue.

Comment: I already said, it would be good if you post the error details. You will find it in the log file. And post the command you are using. It would reveal whether you are connecting to PDB or CDB as root.

Comment: CREATE USER HASTANE IDENTIFIED BY HASTANE DEFAULT TABLESPACE 
USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
GRANT DBA TO HASTANE;

IMP HASTANE/HASTANE FILE=c:\VERI.DMP FULL=Y

i have to create hastane user because for restoring dump is necessary otherwise while restoring database 'hastane user is not existing' error is existing

Comment: And where are you creating the user `HASTANE`? In your local `PDB` or `CDB`? How are you connected to `DB`? It would be good to see your session details.

Comment: i connected /as sysdba and my local is cdb

Comment: You need to connect to `PDB`. Provide the PDB service_name as `sys@pdb as sysdba`

Comment: Problem is solved thanks.

Comment: Somebody downvoted it. Do one thing, combine your comments, and edit your question to add this information. I have just upvoted it. As I feel, it is a good question, since not everyone is comfortable with 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on OP's input via answer to my comments :

`/ AS SYSDBA` will by default connect to `CDB` and not your local `PDB`. There are many ways, however, as of now, you need to first connect to your local `PDB` as:

```
SYS@<pdb service_name> AS SYSDBA
```

Then execute your `CREATE USER` and other commands :

```
CREATE USER HASTANE IDENTIFIED BY HASTANE DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP; 
GRANT DBA TO HASTANE; 
IMP HASTANE/HASTANE FILE=c:\VERI.DMP FULL=Y
```

Answer (score 4):

**Step One: create pdbuser**

1. Run Sqlplus sys/ as sysdba , (if has password you should type it next)
2. run `alter session set container=pdbDBName---;` (eg:pdborcl)
3. run `create user test identified by password default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;`
4. run `grant pdb_dba to test;`
5. run `grant dba to test;`

**Step two: Add pdbname in the tns file**

1. run `CMD`
2. run `tnsping cdbDB` (eg: tnsping orcl)
3. find tns path and open tnsnames.ora file( if not exist make it in same directory of current file)
4. add pdbDBName like cdbDBName(eg:orcl) see below example

example:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) 
    ) 
  ) 

pdbORCL =  
  (DESCRIPTION =  
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))  
    (CONNECT_DATA =  
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)  
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

**Step three: Check tnsping from command prompt**

1. Run `CMD`
2. tnsping pdbDB(eg: tnsping pdborcl)
3. see tns status. it should be ok with path details.

**Step Four connect to  pdbDB**

1. Run Sqlplus
2. test/password@pdborcl-- do not use semicolon. now you are connected to pdb database

**Step Five: Import Dump file**

1. Run `CMD`
2. Type `imp test/password@pdborcl file=myfile.dump`
   now it should start importing process

*Note : if pluggable database is on shutdown mode. mount it to open mode before starting import process*

3. Run Sqlplus
4. connect with sys/ as sysdba (it will connect to cdbdatabase)
5. alter pluggable database all open

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORT PROCEDURE**
For importing full DB dump into 12c database. Assuming that during DB installation you have created container and one pluggable DB (pd1).

**GO to SQL PLUS**

```
CONN / AS SYSDBA
CONN system/syspassword@//localhost:1521/pd1 # connected to pluggable DB 
CREATE USER pdusr IDENTIFIED BY pdpass3344;
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY impdir AS 'C:\app\oracle\oradata\impdir';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY impdir TO pdusr;
GRANT DBA,CONNECT TO pdusr; # granted permissions to pd1 DB because we are connected to mrmspd
```

**Exit sql plus, open CMD**

```
impdp system/syspassword@//localhost:1521/pd1 full=Y directory=impdir dumpfile=expdat.dmp logfile=impdp_mrms.log
```

And make sure you put expdat.dmp in C:\app\oracle\oradata\impdir

Answer (score 0):

First learn something about that database. Here is a document about usermanagement in 12c
[Administering User Accounts and Security](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/users_secure.htm#ADMQS007)
The [DBA essentials](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm) in general is a very good starting point

You are looking in the root of a container database and you need to create your users in a local PDB and import your data in there. Easiest is to create a tnsalias for that pdb that points to the specific PDB service_name for the import.

Comment: You are simply assuming things since OP has not mentioned any error details. Based on OP's explanation, I am expecting `ORA-65094:invalid local user or role name` error. But, OP needs to tell us exactly.

Comment: OP mentioned c## needed as prefix for usernames, being required for common users.... Not really an assumption.

Comment: my dump file don't have username starting with c##.is that possible to restore database according to the session ?

Comment: In order to be able to import the database into a pdb, you need to connect to the pdb and not to the container database. Make a tnsalias for your pdb and connect to the pdb using that alias. Create your users and import what you want. You could use sqlplus / as sysdba to connect to the container and issue 'alter session set container = your_pdb_name' before you start creating your users.